# Patterns of screen scrolling and tapping and instantaneous mood

Tags: social-networks, brain-computer-interface, mood, prosocial-behavior, comparative-cognition

I was wondering whether any surveys have been conducted to see if people click more often on things (at a given timing), in Google Discover, and similar, news, apps, when they're depressed.

Another situation could be not clicking on something in Quora or in a similar social app, because of avoidance. This could also have a specific scrolling pattern.

Another, type, of slow slowly accelerating scrolling, and then tapping (screens do not yet have the capability to detect a difference between a depressed tap with a nail, and a positive tap with the index finger, including, an analysis of the pressure, from, such, ... but a capability may be embedded in phones in the future).

So, I was wondering, what research has been done in this area (including research aimed at detecting, escaping, from these patterns).

Thanks.